# Constant battery voltage

Tags: batteries, step-down

I purchased a RC car and tore out the electronics and replaced with an Arduino. I am powering the DC motor from the battery but when it loses capacity it loses power. So the current is varying.

For example: when I run the motor at 50 and its charged it goes fast but even ten minutes later it's significantly slower for the same code.

7.2v Ni-MH 6cell 
Arduino uno
Vnh5019 motor shield:  Battery plugged directly into there and also powers the uno since they stack.

I was wondering if I should use a linear regulator or buck converter to have a constant voltage or if there's a better solution.  I am new to electronics.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of battery are we talking about here?

Comment: The Arduino may be consuming much more current than the original electronics. It may be overkill for the simple work it has to do.

Comment: Sorry edited the post.

Comment: What do you mean you run the motor at 50? You do not get the same speed with constant duty cycle?

Comment: Like on the arduino dc motor shield code I have. I pwm at a set value and as the battery drains the speed changes significantly. I can show you exact code soon if that helps. Allows like -400 to 400 int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good idea to rely on voltage to control a motor accurately, you need some sort of feedback. The ordinary way to do this for DC motors (as opposed to steppers or servos) is by using a [rotary encoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotary_encoder). Even if your motor does not have one integrated, it should be easy to build an optical encoder yourself: you print the stripe pattern on a transparent disk, attach said disc to the axle and attach a light source and detector in such a way that the light path gets interrupted by the dark parts.

With this signal you measure how much the motor *actually* turned and control it accordingly. A rather simple yet most likely sufficient way to do this is called [PID controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller). For fast driving it is probably better to control the speed, for slow and accurate driving the distance.

---

Regulating the voltage is indeed important for many circuits, but does probably not make sense for motors; you have nothing to gain from it if you employ feedback anyway, but it has losses. 
Generally you want to use buck converters for large differences in voltage (low losses but moderate ripples) and linear converters for small differences (much heat is generated but the voltage is very smooth (good for analog circuits and such).

---

The usage of NI-MH smells a bit fishy to me: depending on how much current the motors draw they might suffer quite high internal losses (look up 'equivalent series resistance' in the datasheet). If that is the case you can either put more batteries in parallel or use Li-ion batteries.

Comment: Your question seemed (to me at least) to pose a [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY%20Problem). I hope I guessed correctly what you meant, if not leave a comment so I can edit accordingly. If my answer was helpful, consider editing the question a bit to make it better searchable (for ease of future people with the same problem)